# Jquery auto-appending new input, prevent on previous

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to build a invoice form that automatically creates the next input field when the last created input receives focus, e.g. is tabbed into.

I have the basic functionality that I want, but with one problem.  I only want a new field appended when just the **very last** input receives focus, but currently it still appends a new field as well if **any previous** field receives focus.

My thought was to add a "new" class to the last field, and then remove it when the next input is appended, but because I am using a delegate function on #invoice that does not have the desired effect.

[jFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rea0edeh/)

```
$(function() {
var wrapper = $(".clone_services"); //Input wrapper
var x = 1; //initial index count
  $('#invoice').on('focus', '.clone_services', function(){
      $('.new').focus(function(){ //on add input button click
        $(this).removeClass('new');
        $(wrapper).append('<br><input type="text" class="services new" name="services['+ x +']"/>');
        }); 
  });
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rea0edeh/3/

There is no need of adding `focus` event to 2 elements. Just one is enough.

```
$(function() {
    var wrapper = $(".clone_services"); //Input wrapper
    var x = 1; //initial index count
      $('.clone_services').on('focus','.new' , function(){
            $(this).removeClass('new');
            $(wrapper).append('<br><input type="text" class="services new" name="services['+ x +']"/>');
          x++;
            }); 

});
```

Comment: Ahh.  Now I see my mistake.  That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.clone_services > .new', function () {
    var $line = $(this).clone();
    $(this).removeClass('new').closest('.clone_services').append($line);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rea0edeh/4/

You can combine it with

```
$(document).on('blur', '.clone_services > *', function () {
    if ( $.trim( $(this).val()) === "" ) $(this).remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rea0edeh/5/

Comment: That's very nice. I don't completely understand how it works though. What does this `.clone_services > .new'` part do?

Comment: Never mind.  I was not recognizing it as a selector.  I was thinking it was a greater than symbol.

Comment: @skribe I must ask this: You get two answers that help you and upvote none of them... What's the reason?